# Vue.js: Update second property during calculation of computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Example: Based on a list of nodes and edges I want to calculate a graph object. Also I am interested in the longest path of the calculated graph. For my understanding a straight-forward implmentation would be:

```
Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            myNodes: {/*list of nodes*/},
            myEdges: {/*list of edges*/}
    },
    methods: {
        calculateGraph(nodes, edges) {/* complex calculation */},
        calculateLongestPath(graph) {/* more complex calculation */}
    }
    computed: {
        myGraph: function {
            return calculateGraph(this.myNodes,this.myEdges)
        }
        myLongestPath: function {
            return calculateLongestPath(this.myGraph)
        }
    }
}
```

However, assuming the longest path could be calculated directly during the construction of the graph (for performance), the code could look like this:

```
Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            myNodes: {/*list of nodes*/},
            myEdges: {/*list of edges*/},
            myLongestPath: null
    },
    methods: {
        calculateGraph(nodes, edges) {
            /* complex calculation */
            this.myLongestPath = /* calculated value */
        }            
    }
    computed: {
        myGraph: function {
            return calculateGraph(this.myNodes,this.myEdges)
        }
    }
}
```

Is the second implementation good practise in Vue.js? Is there a better third option between readability (1) and unnecessary complex function `calculateLongestPath` (2)?

Comment: What you do inside `calculateGraph` is a so called side effect, which should be avoided in computed properties as it might lead to endless loops. Nevertheless, the it is neither a good approach in Vue nor in other frameworks. Just think of how you will test the implementation.

Comment: You are right and that's my issue. Version 1 is much cleaner code and more easy to debug and test. However, it requires an unnecessary algorithm for the calculation of the path.